# GridView Images Download

Tags: android, gridview

i am creating a [gridview](/questions/tagged/gridview) activity which downloads the images asynchronously as in the example in android developers. When some images aren't downloaded correctly, because of slow internet connection, i have one refresh button that downloads only these images and not all from the beginning. The problem is how can   i bind these images to their unique image-view in grid-view?

Answer (score 0):

Override the `getItem(int)` method of your adapter, and use it to get the ImageView.

```
public Object getItem(int position) {
     return myCollection[position];
}




public void update(Drawable draw, int position) {
     ImageView view = (ImageView) mAdapter.getItem(position);
     view.setImageDrawable(draw);
     mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

Comment: i haven't tested your code yet because i can't find the error images. Once i will fix this i will tell you! Thanks in advance!